# java (jdk 1.6) regular expression

Tags: java, regex, java-6

I want to check whether any special character exist in given string.
I tried following pattern but didn't worked. So it will be helpful if any valid answers.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\*&]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("a*a&a");
boolean b = m.matches();

if (b) {
    System.out.println("Found");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not Found");
}
```

Its working in javascript. ie [\*&].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
boolean b = m.matches();
```

use:

```
boolean b = m.find();
```

As `Matcher#matches` returns true only when it matches full input from start to end.

Comment: +1 This is even better as you are not trying to match only checking if it contains

Answer (score 0):

`matches()` auto-anchors the regex with `^` and `$` (respectively start-of-the-line and end-of-the-line). You're regex is thus transformed into `^[\\*&]$`, which will match only the strings `"*"` and `"&"`.

You're looking for: `.*[\\*&].*`

Side note: you don't need to escape `*` when nested in a class: `[*&]` behaves as `[\\*&]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yours doesn't match because it is only looking for `*` and `&`

A simple way to look that it `contains` is by enclosing that regex with `.*` at the beginning and end such as:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*[\\*&].*");
```